# Are reliability and validity measures necessary for all parts of a survey

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, confirmatory-factor, validity, cronbachs-alpha

I am conducting analysis on a questionnaire which was a three-part study, not three separate studies. I asked the same exact set of validated scale questions for specific constructs for three different brands, but it was all within the same survey and had the same sample. Is it necessary for me to conduct construct validity via factor analysis and reliability via Cronbach's alpha three separate times, or should I combine all of the responses (granted there are almost 40 items in total for the four constructs...times three begins to be a lot) or is there a simpler way to do it. Or do I simply run it three separate times and write it up as such in my thesis.

Thank you

Comment: Your objective of study is not clear from details as listed .

Comment: So you ask the same questions about three different brands and want to know if you should do factor analysis and Cronbach's alpha on the data from each brand separately or all the data combined? Please confirm this, and also, as Subhash asked, what the ultimate goal (and analytical framework) is the for the study.